# CSS : Automatic width variable calculation

Tags: html, css, helper

Hi @all !

let's say I have 2 helper classes as :

```
.w3-4 {
  width: calc((100% / 4) * 3);
}

// AND

.mr-10 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Do you think there is a automated pure css way to substract the margin value from `.mr-10` to the width from `.w3-4` ?

Something such as

```
.mr-10 {
  margin-right: 10px;

  // width calc
  width: calc(--width - 10px);
}
```

There are plenty of ways to do this with SASS or even JS, but I'm just a bit lazy and curious :)

Thanks for your answers,

A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare `--width` variable in all width classes and manupulate width in margin css

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.w3-4 {
  width: calc((100% / 4) * 3);
  --width: calc((100% / 4) * 3);
}
.w1-2 {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  --width: calc(100% / 2);
}
.w1-4 {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  --width: calc(100% / 4);
}


.mr-10 {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: calc(var(--width) - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-4">
width 3/4
</div>
<div class="w1-2">
width 1/2
</div>
<div class="w1-4">
width 1/4
</div>
<div class="w3-4 mr-10">
width 3/4 with 10px margin-right
</div>
<div class="w1-2 mr-10">
width 1/2 with 10px margin-right
</div>
<div class="w1-4 mr-10">
width 1/4 with 10px margin-right
</div>
```

Comment: All right !
So we have to declare the variable, there is no `"this element width" - 10px` for example ?
But this is close from what I'm looking for, thanks a lot :)

Comment: >`width: calc(var(--width) - 10px);`: How does this work when `--width: calc(100% / 2);` is set in some ancestor element? How is that 100% / 2 calculated?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this like

```
.mr-10 {
    width: calc((100% / 4) * 3 - 25px);
}
```

**where 25px value can vary**

Comment: Yeah but the issue with this solution is that I can't reuse the snippet.

I have multiple helper classes such as `.w1-4`, `.w2-4`, etc. I'm looking for a DRY solution but in plain css :)

Comment: Okay, then you need to fix it or use any server side language to achieve this. Server side language can be PHP or any which you are using

Comment: I understand, CSS has not implement this utility for now.

Actually the answer from @supraja just above is close from what I'm looking for, in plain CSS.

Still a superfluous line, but I suppose there is not a "this.width" equivalent in CSS yet

Comment: yes right :-) you can accept any answer no worries.